# In Django, how to click button to call a view and then reload page

Tags: ajax, django

In Django, how to click button on page without passing any value to view.py and then reloading current page? I have a button in the HTML:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="refresh">refresh page</button>
```

I want to call a view in view.py, in which new HTML will be returned:

```
@csrf_exempt
def topology_show_refresh(request):
    '''topology refresh'''
    plan = {...}
    ...
    return render(request, 'topology_show.html', {'plan': plan})
```

The `plan` dictionary will be used in the new page.

```
    {% if plan.try == 'first' %}
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var max_lane_num = {{plan.max_lane_num}};
            var flag = 0;
        </script>
    {% else %}
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var max_lane_num = {{plan.lane_second}};
            var flag = 1;
        </script>
    {% endif %}
```

In my way, I use ajax to jump to this view, but I have no idea how to handle the return, e.g., pass the `plan` to HTML.

```
$(function(){
    $("#refresh").click(function(event){
        url = 'refresh/';
        $.post(url, {}, function(ret){
            //do something
            //how to pass "plan" dictionary to HTML
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are very close to the task of reloading page,
Use 'location.reload(true)' instead of 'window.location.reload();'

And handle the response data by success() function.
Try this :

```
    $(function(){
        $("#refresh").click(function(event){
            $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: 'refresh/',
              success:function(response) {
              location.reload(true);

              //do something with 'response'
             }
            });
    });
```

Comment: Hi, Prakhar, I've edited problem how to pass `plan` dictionary from ajax to HTML

Comment: @vinllen if you need to reload page and go to view,why are you using javascript.It can simply be done by adding <a href> tag to the button.

Comment: @vinllen Like this <a href="/refresh/"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="refresh">refresh page</button></a>

Comment: force reload is no longer required
location.reload() should be enough in this case
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55127650/location-reloadtrue-is-deprecated