# location.reload(true) is deprecated

Tags: javascript, angular, reload, tslint

I know that it is not ideal to reload an Angular Single Page Application. However there is a place that I need to reload the full application.

TSLint says that reload is deprecated.

Is there any alternative for this?

Comment: it's only the forceReload flag that's deprecated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to reload a page using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3715047/how-to-reload-a-page-using-javascript)

Comment: It's pretty useful in some browsers like Firefox, but if you remove that, you will have to come up with a way to force reload it.

Answer (score 66):

You can use `location.reload()` without the forceReload flag.
This is just deprecated because it is not in the spec: https://www.w3.org/TR/html50/browsers.html#dom-location-reload

Comment: So, in my case, why does TSLint warn me ? : `window.location.reload.bind(window.location)`

Comment: What can I do if I want to do a forced reload?

Comment: And now how to force the full reload?

Comment: location.reload() doesn't work for Edge in production

Comment: Doesn't work in Chrome also

Answer (score 57):

If you look at interface definition for Location you will see the following:

```
/**
 * Reloads the current page.
 */
reload(): void;
/** @deprecated */
reload(forcedReload: boolean): void;
```

Using `location.reload()` is the valid syntax. It is only the reload with forcedReload which is deprecated.

In your case changing `location.reload(true)` to `location.reload()` to resolve your issue.

Answer (score 42):

Since the `forceReload` parameter is deprecated, as 3 people already mentioned, it is also ignored by some browsers already.

Using only `location.reload();` is not a solution if you want to perform a force-reload (as done with e.g. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd>) in order to reload all resources from the server and not from the browser cache.

The solution to this issue is, to execute a `POST` request to the current location as this always makes the browser to reload everything.

`location.reload()` is only executing a `GET` request.

So I came to the workaround to place an empty form on the Angular app with `method="POST"` and `action="https://example.org/"` and then submitting that form from code-behind when wanted.

Template:

```
<form [action]="myAppURL" method="POST" #refreshForm></form>
```

Code-behind / component:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  // bla bla bla Mr. Freeman
})
export class FooComponent {
  @ViewChild('refreshForm', { static: false }) refreshForm;

  forceReload() {
    this.refreshForm.nativeElement.submit();
  }
}
```

I guess this can be also done in a more non-hacky way. I am investigating... (HttpClient, maybe?)

Comment: I get `Cannot POST /`

Comment: I think THIS is the best idea!!

Comment: I also get   Cannot POST /

Comment: @NemanjaAndric how can I solve this? do you get the answer?

Comment: Also getting: POST http://localhost:3000/login 404 (Not Found)

Answer (score 14):

Since `window.location.reload(true)` has been deprecated. You can use:

`window.location.href = window.location.href`,

to force-reload and clear the cache.

Comment: Even better than this, use window.location.replace(window.location.href) -- this does not add an entry in the browser history like a simple assignment does.

Comment: This does not trigger a reload (at least FF on MacOS tested) until I change the URL by appending a timestamp or somewhat else.

Answer (score 13):

According to Martin Schneider answer, you can create a function, and then just call it

```
forceReload() {
    if(environment.production) {
        const form = document.createElement('form');
        form.method = "POST";
        form.action = location.href;
        document.body.appendChild(form);
        form.submit();
    } else {
        window.location.reload();
    }
}
```

Good luck !

Comment: This did not do anything when I placed it behind the body tag of my page.

Answer (score 8):

Changing **location.reload(true)** to **location.reload()** works.
forcedReload is the one which is deprecated.

Answer (score 2):

I created a small package in order to have a solution to clean the cache and reload the page if necessary: https://www.npmjs.com/package/clear-cache

`clearCache()` or `clearCache(false)` when you only want to clear cache but don't want to reload the page.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best and most effective way to refresh (not just reload) the page is using a form with method="post", an empty action, and a submit button, since "post" requests are never cached. Simple and effective, and it even works with no JavaScript at all!

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <button type="Submit">Refresh</button>
</form>
```

If you need to do it programatically, you can just hide the button with CSS and trigger the click action in the button with JavaScript.

Thanks to @Martin Schneider for his idea.

Comment: This reloaded the page, but still used cached images in Chrome and Edge.

Comment: This refreshes the PAGE, not the images. If you want to force images reloading as well, you have to call them with a random query string or timestamp/date string (I.e: <img src="image.jpg?ts=123456789">)